# unable to attach. process ’ c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' is not running on xxx

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

Yesterday There was a windows 11 update and today, every azure function I try to debug in VS2022 (Version 17.7.3), even out of the box Function1 project, Shows error:

"**Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated.
System.Private.CoreLib: A task was canceled.**"

There is also a message box
[image]

I tried rebooting and checked the path it does contain C:\Program Files\dotnet

I tried the same thing in VS Code that also worked before and I am getting
**Failed to find "func: host start" task.**

Any help?

Comment: Please try upgrading the package versions of your Azure function.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1458

Comment: I have the latest everything  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />

Answer (score 0):

- Install [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2174087) **version 4**:

Open Terminal in VSCode  and run the command:

`npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true`

[image]

- Check if there are any updates to be done.
- Create a new function project with the below package versions:

**.csproj:**

```html
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.18.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.13.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

local.settings.json:

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

**Run the function:**

[image]

**References:**

[Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated · Issue #1514](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1514)

Comment: The problem is in VS2022 not VS Code.

Comment: can you check by installing [Azure core function tools v4](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2174087)

Comment: No. Microsoft tech support is moving it from one hand to another.